# How to know what folders recently use a lot hard disk space in Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space

I'm using Win Dir Stats now but it can't tell which folder RECENTLY increased the use of space.

Comment: Check the file dates of big files. Also use Tree Size (Jam Software) as that will show you the dates of files. Recent big changes will have recent files dates corresponding. Tree Size (Admin) will show you hidden files doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Tree Size Example. See the folder sorted down the side by size. I pick out a Virtual Machine and it has today's date for Change date / time

[image]

You may need to keep track of very large files over a few days to see what changes have occurred. I do not know of any file explorer tools that will give you this history, but once you know the big files (probably few), they are easy to track.

Comment: What software is this?

Comment: Tree Size Professional is the software I used to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has a feature built into the settings that might be some help as to see what folders are taking up space on your hard drive.

To access that follow the following steps

- Hit the Windows key
- Click on the Gear icon to go to settings
- Click on system
- In the sidebar click on storage

From there it should show you places where storage is currently being taken up refer to picture below

[image]

Most likely the it wont categorize the files thats causing your problem and you would need to check under Other to see what folders might be taking up the most space

Comment: WinDirStat does it better. But still, both don't show RECENT disk space used.

Comment: So you want to be able to see when it was last modified? Then I'd recommend TreefileSize as pointed out by @John its a piece of software i have used before and is much newer than WinDirStat it will display the last modified date of a folder as well as its size [Picture](https://imgur.com/a/AN1ZM26)